# Is it possible to get detailed error messages in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, logging, debugging

When doing any sort of development/testing work against SharePoint Online, there are bound to be some errors. Some errors manifest in the form of exceptions, which can be logged to a special-purpose SharePoint list for error details. Other errors, though, cannot be caught as exceptions. For instance:

```
Error 
Sandboxed code execution request failed. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 9cde387c-b460-4731-9681-450a7c890310 

Date and Time: 5/16/2012 4:42:13 AM
```

On the server version, I would check the logs for the correlation ID to get a detailed stack trace, conditions around the error, etc. Is there any way to get this log information in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You best chance is to try at least four things while debugging:

- Use logging library "[SharePoint Sandbox Logging"](http://spsl.codeplex.com/) to log errors on
  feature activation, as you probably know logging capabilities on
  Sandbox are limited.
- Have Correlation Id with your error? contact Microsoft support
- Review SharePoint logs for on-premises Sandbox to check for any
  errors, warnings that appear during activation
- [Try Literal Debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2011/05/31/mvps-for-sharepoint-2010-debugging-techniques-for-sharepoint-online-applications.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming your third point means testing in a local farm before deployment to SharePoint Online? The problem is there often seem to pop up problems in SharePoint Online which don't manifest in the local sandbox. That "Literal debugging" link is priceless, by the way. Very retro.

Comment: Yup, on-premises stands for you local Sandbox solution, really, worth a try